# Existe alguna cosa que funcione igual que esto pero para un Datagrid en WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

```
DataTable distinctTable = dtEmp.DefaultView.ToTable( /*distinct*/ true);
```

Segun he leido esto hace que las filas no se repitan, necesito algo asi pero para un DataGrid y no encuentro logica para hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver, no tengo el PC a mano para esto, pero tomando en cuenta esta pregunta y la otra que apunta a lo mismo, te dejo este ejemplo de como puedes usar Distinct.

```
static void Filtrar()
{
    List<Data> listaConRepetidos = new List<Data>();
    List<Data> listaSinRepetidos = new List<Data>();
    //Acá metes todos tus items a la lista con repetidos
    ...
    
    //Creas una variable que tenga los elementos sin repetir
    var MS = listaConRepetidos.Distinct();
    //También lo puedes hacer con Linq, agrega using System.Linq arriba
    var QS = (from d in listaConRepetidos select d).Distinct();
    //ahora recorres la lista
    foreach (var item in MS)
    {
        //Acá puedes ir agregando los items que quedaron directo al DataGrid
        DG_scanner.Items.Add(item);
        //o agregarlo a la lista que está al inicio del método
        listaSinRepetidos.Add(item);
    }
    
    //si agregas los items a la lista del inicio entonces acá
    //asignas el ItemsSource del DataGrid (DG_scanner) que es esa lista.
    DG_scanner.ItemsSource = listaSinRepetidos;
    
    
    //Con Linq puedes decirle al método que campos considerar para el Distinct 
    
    var lst = listaConRepetidos.Select(m => new {m.hostname , m.maccaddress}).Distinct();
    
    //Finalmente toda la operación sería algo como esto:
    
    var listaSinRepetidos = listaConRepetidos
    .Select(m => new {m.hostname, m.maccaddress})
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
    
    DG_scanner.DataSource     = listaSinRepetidos;
    DG_scanner.DisplayMemberPath  = "hostname";
    DG_scanner.SelectedValuePath = "maccaddress";
}
```

Espero se entienda, te puse varios ejemplos en 1 así que lee bien los comentarios de linea.
Bye.